# Preserving Law of Demeter with ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist, refactoring, law-of-demeter

If I have an ArrayList of objects then any time I need to call any method on a member of the ArrayList I need to do it like this:

```
list.get(i).doSomething();
```

This looks suspiciously like a Law of Demeter violation. I can not see any way of getting around this. Is this fine or should I rethink how I do things like this. Is the ArrayList an object defined to ignore the Law of Demeter?

Comment: Could you explain how you see a Law of Demeter violation?

Comment: Maybe describe more of what you want to do? I don't see an issue here, it's not like you're calling 10 getters on a row.

Comment: I realise this isn't a huge violation but it still seems like a code smell. It is a LoD violation because I am retrieving an object from the ArrayList and then calling a method on the retrieved object. Technically I should do something like list.callSomethingOn(i) to preserve the Law of Demeter but that seems wrong as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a violation.

If you had a class

```
Class A {
    private B b1, b2, b3;

    ...

   private void method() {
       b1.doSomething();
       b2.doSomething();
       b3.doSomething();
   }
}
```

there is no violation. If we collect the instance of `B` into a `List<B>` you get

```
Class A {
    private List<B> listOfB;

    ...

   private void method() {
       listOfB.forEach(B::doSomething);
   }
}
```

Using an `List<B>` to hold the instances of `B` results in no tighter coupling between `A` and `B`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see a violation here.

The Law of Demeter, in concept, proposes that an entity only knows of its neighbors, not strangers, so if `A` needs something from `C`, it should talk to `B` to get it and not go any further.

I wouldn't exactly call a `List` a "neighbor" to apply to this concept. It's an object that manipulates a data structure which you can use throughout your program. Therefore, the `Object` that your list contains would be considered the `B` to your `A`.

If `List` was an actual entity defined in your program, you could be right in this case. It would make more sense to have your `List` have a method which calls for your `Object` to perform some logic (as you said in a comment, `list.callSomethingOn(i)`).

If this particular instance of `List` is central to your program's logic and you're adamant about satisfying the law, you could use a "Decorator" for the `List` which adds additional methods to work with the contained `Object`s